# Скрипт работает только 1 раз в расширении chrome

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Дело в том, что мне нужно при каждом обновлении страницы изменять её, но работает это только 1 раз. [Вот сама страница](https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_browse)
   Вот код:

```
function hideBtn(){
  $('.btn-orange').hide();
  $('.btn-primary').hide();
  $('.item-amount').css("color", "red");
 };
$(window).ready(function(){
 hideBtn();
});
```

Comment: Вернее, он работает всегда, но нужно заходить на другую вкладку, пока эта не загрузилась

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы прелоадер работал при обновлении страницы?

Comment: Без разницы, главное, чтобы всегда работало

Comment: если очищаю куки и кэш все сразу пашет, я скорее всего думаю что у вас кэшируется файл

Comment: Можно ли как-то его убрать?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/154643/ там все подробно описано

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зацикли его. Например при помощи `setInterval` или `setTimeout`. Можешь в `requestAnimationFrame` запихнуть. Это вот основные вещи при помощи которых можно заставить что-то выполняться циклично.